# angular2 Dependency injection to static method results to ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following custom validator, which i want to use to check from server that username/email address is not already taken. I have my `checkUser` method in `NewUserService` class, which i'm trying to inject to `shouldBeUnique` method.

NewUserValidator class

```
export class NewUserValidator {
static shouldBeUnique(control: Control, service: NewUserService) {

    service.checkUser("test")
        .subscribe(posts => console.log(posts));

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){

            if (control.value == "test") {
                resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
            } else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        }, 1000);

    });
}
```

NewUserService class

```
checkUser(email) : Observable<newUser> {

    let body = JSON.stringify(

        {   "email": email
        });

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    return this._http.post(this._urlCheckUser, body, options)
        .map(res => res.json());

}
```

When typing something to field where the validator kicks in, i get this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkUser' of
>   undefined

Everything works ok without this code:

```
    service.checkUser("test")
        .subscribe(posts => console.log(posts));
```

Comment: how does NewUserService class look like?

Comment: have you imported `import {NewUserService } from './path'` and injected it into `bootstrap` or component's `providers` meta data

Comment: Angular DI doesn't inject to static methods, only to constructors. Make it a normal service without a static method instead.